# How to get headers element in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I would like to get headers element in server side with node js I try these two codes in client side:

> CODE 1

```
 var token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0ayI6IjU5Mjg0YjQ0MzNhNjU2MmRlNDI1ZGU5MCIsImlhdCI6MTQ5NjY5NjA1NiwiZXhwIjoyOTkzMzk1NzEyfQ.BQskPVT-h-Io4p3Hqraq2qRmVlp_pWAEw5rnIIEA4vk';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'YourRestEndPoint',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'Basic' + token
        },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: YourData,
        success: function(data){
          console.log('succes: '+data);
        }
      });
```

> Code 2:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn",
         data: { signature: authHeader },
         type: "GET",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader(                               
          'Authorization':'Basic' + token);
         },
         success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
});
```

And here the code server:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");

console.log(req.headers['authorization']);
```

I can't get the token in the server side.

Comment: Where is `req` defined in your server code? Can you specify the error you are getting from the console?

Comment: router.use(function(req, res, next) {
...
console.log(req.headers['authorization']);
...
}

Answer (score 0):

In Code 1, you have `'Authorization'` as the property name in your header. However, in your code, you `console.log` `'authorization'`.

Try the same capitalization of both. *Let me know if the capital was an error with copying and pasting.*

Comment: > console.log(req.headers['Authorization']); 
>undefined

Comment: I got these two error in console browser:
>OPTIONS http://localhost:8181/users 403 (Forbidden)

>XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8181/users. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403